# Spring Kafka: C++ producer of reply for ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: c++, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, librdkafka

I use ReplyingKafkaTemplate to send a request to Kafka and receive the reply.
Consumer of the request is a C++ program. After processing the request, its reply is produced by the C++ application. Now my problem is about format of the reply, because it seems that consumer of the reply in spring-side uses correlation Id to find corresponding reply.
Can somebody help me about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo back the correlationId header so the template knows which request this reply is for. Simply set the header on the reply in your C++ code to the value of the incoming request header.